# Creating Disconnected DataRows in .NET

Tags: .net, ado.net, system.data.datatable

How do you create DataRow instances that aren't tied to any particular DataTable instance?

(EDIT: I know you can create DataRows using the DataTable.NewRow() method, but the problem is that I can't seem to disconnect the row from its parent table so I can pass the individual row around without having to pass the entire table around)

Comment: Please give more context for what you're trying to do. There may be a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could *try* is deleting it immediately:

```
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row.Delete();
```

That will put it in a `DataRowState` of Detached, which sounds like what you want. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve in terms of a bigger picture though, so this may not help.

Answer (score 0):

I rather would only copy the content of the DataRow. You can achive that with:

```
row.ItemArray
```

I think that would be a better approch, than trying to get a workaround for the lacking copy functionality.